# gocd docker container not sving pipelines

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-volume, go-cd

I'm trying to setup GoCD using the GoCD-Server docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/gocd/gocd-server/

I'm mounting the volumes as they suggest to: 
`docker run -v /Users/me/LocalDocuments/gocd/godata:/godata -v /Users/me/LocalDocuments/gocd/home/go:/home/go -p8153:8153 -p8154:8154 gocd/gocd-server`

but pipelines (or anything else) aren't saving to the folders mounted and they are not persisted when I shutdown the container.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version `17.3.0` solved this issue. It seems like the image I was using was created 7 weeks ago.